# How to prevent Qt Designer from loading incompatible plugins?

Tags: qt, plugins, qt-creator, qt-designer

Qt Designer and Qt Creator when trying to edit ui files have started to crash recently. I've found it's because of KDE widget plugins that are built for a previous version. However, I can't find a way to disable them. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Qt Designer, there is a config option that allows you to disable specific plugins. Exactly how you do this may differ for each platform, but on my Arch Linux system I have the following config files:

- Qt5: *$HOME/.config/QtProject/Designer.conf*
- Qt4: *$HOME/.config/Trolltech/Designer.conf*

And in the Qt5 file, I have disabled all the KDE plugins by adding a section like this:

```
[PluginManager]
DisabledPlugins=/usr/lib/qt/plugins/designer/kdewebkit5widgets.so, /usr/lib/qt/plugins/designer/kf5deprecatedwidgets.so, /usr/lib/qt/plugins/designer/kf5widgets.so
```

So it's just a matter of adding the full path of any plugin you want to disable to a comma-separated list.

I don't use Qt Creator, but if the above doesn't work, I understand it may also be possible to disable plugins via Help -> About Plugins.